# Memory buildup with Serilog Periodic Batching sink under high load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, android-3.0-honeycomb

We reacently added a [Serilog sink](https://github.com/evilpilaf/HoneycombSerilogSink) to push events into [Honeycomb](https://www.honeycomb.io/) that's built on top of Serilog's Periodic Batching sink, but when deployed we see the memory usage skyrockets.

After managing to get a memory dump we see the main culprit being the `_queue` within the PeriodicBatching sink to be the one hogging it.

This behaviour is seen consistently across all instances and we wonder if it might be a bug in the sink or queue implementation.

[image: Memory usage of Serilog sink]

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler?  I would be looking for the GC roots on that object.

Comment: The screenshot comes from dotTrace from the memdump, we've tried to replicate the conditions locally to no success due to the very high traffic this site gets. The number of elements seems correct, as they are all log messages from the system and in high traffic there's a ton. I wonder more if the queue is not being emptied on time.

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug or memory leak to me too.  I'm not familiar with the library though.  That said it is on GitHub so you could clone the repo and look at the code that might be causing it.  I would suggest taking two dumps to see if the queue is getting drained at all.  That could narrow it down.

Comment: Can you share which version of the library you are using?

Comment: @evilpilaf I'm curious where this issue ended up.